# How to show multiple list views within a datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datagrid

In my program i currently have a datagrid with a modified row template which displays a list view. So when a user selects a row in the datagrid, the row expands and shows a list view, and when a user selects a different row, the original list collapses and the list for the new row expands. I have now been asked to make it allow multiple list views to be expanded and am unsure of how to do this.

My xaml code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Accounts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAccount}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Width="Auto">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView MaxHeight="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedAccount.Details, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedDetail, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                          Tools:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Account" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AccountCode}" 
                                            Tools:GridViewSort.PropertyName="AccountCode" Width="Auto" />

                            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"
                                            Tools:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Description" Width="Auto"/>                                  
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListView.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ListView">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedAccount.Details.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Style>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountTitle}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So i have a list of accounts shown in my datagrid, and on each account there is a list of details which is shown on the listview which appears when an account is selected. How can i keep the details from the originally selected account in the listview visible when other accounts are selected?

Comment: What you are Expecting? Should the RowDetails remain Visible after some other row is Selected

Comment: yeh that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this if you want the detailsTemplate of previously Selected Rows remain Visible. You subscribe the **RowDetailsVisibilityChanged** event of DataGrid like

```
<DataGrid  RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="DataGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged_1">
        .......
        ........
    </DataGrid>

private void DataGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged_1(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    { 
        e.Row.DetailsVisibility= Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

I hope this will help.